# Drupal - Add class to menu of number of items it contains?

Tags: drupal-theming

How can I add a class to a menu of the number of items it contains?

My site has a menu that will always have either 7 or 8 items, as one will be regularly be enabled and disabled. I want to style the links slightly differently in either case. If the menu had a class of the number of items being used this would be easy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to override [theme_menu_item_link](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_menu_item_link/6), and add the mlid to the actual link.

Drop this snippet into your template.php file and as per usual, replace themeName with your themes name.

```
<?php
function themeName_menu_item_link($link) {
  if (empty($link['localized_options'])) {
    $link['localized_options'] = array();
  }
  if (empty($link['localized_options']['attributes']['class'])) {
    $link['localized_options']['attributes']['class'] = 'menu-'. $link['mlid'];
  }
  else {
    $link['localized_options']['attributes']['class'] .= ' menu-'. $link['mlid'];
  }
  return l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link['localized_options']);
}
?>
```

for reference ee that link 
http://adaptivethemes.com/how-to-add-unique-classes-to-drupal-menus

My Reards

Comment: Nothing happens but the only change ive made is to replace themeName with my theme name. Do I need to add some PHP to count the number of items and assign it as a class? Thanks

Comment: you want to different between the enabled one from the disabled one by adding class to styling it, the code above is to add class with id of link, you may make it fixed to "menu-enabled" and "menu-disabled"

you need to edit your css file.

Comment: Ah, so will the solution only work if a menu link is enabled or disabled in the menu admin interface? Thanks

Comment: this code will add class to every link with its id, so you can style menus items as you want, you can make each item with unique style represent its function to make it more easy ... just to have control to what you need of items ... My Regards

Comment: sorry i guess i wasnt clear, what I need is for the actual menu or a div that contains everything to have a class or id dependent on how many links their are. so if there is an extra link i can have less padding on all the links. thanks